# Getting Edittext values

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application Two edit boxes are there,when clicking appropriate Editbox it will show An listview(which is another intent.From that user have to select 1 input,i am assigning these value to the textbox.Myproblem is when i set value for 1 editbox and clicking another textbox to get values the 1st textbox value is not there.

My Code is:

Screen with edittext box:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        final String fromunit=getIntent().getStringExtra("Fromunit");
        final String tounit=getIntent().getStringExtra("Tounit");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);       
        EditText medit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText meditfrom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        EditText meditto=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        meditfrom.setText(fromunit);
        meditto.setText(tounit);
        meditfrom.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) 
Intent  FromIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(),Fromlist.class);
                 startActivity(FromIntent); 
                return false;
            }
        });

  meditto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent  ToIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(),Tolist.class);
                 startActivity(ToIntent);   
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The ListView Screen:

FOR 1st editbox:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fromunit, FROMUNIT));
                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
    //                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Intent prev=new Intent(view.getContext(),ServiceExampleActivity.class);
                      prev.putExtra("Fromunit",((TextView) view).getText());
                      startActivity(prev);
                  }
                });        
            }   


For 2nd edittextbox:



 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fromunit, TOUNIT));
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    //            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
    //                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Intent prev=new Intent(view.getContext(),ServiceExampleActivity.class);
                  prev.putExtra("Tounit",((TextView) view).getText());
                  startActivity(prev);
              }
            });        
        }
```

Comment: Rather than EditText/Listview, why don't you use a spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForresult()` method to start another Activity

eg: In FirstActivity

```
 int REQUEST_CODE= 1;

 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) 
  Intent  FromIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(),Fromlist.class);
             startActivityForresult(FromIntent,REQUEST_CODE); 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In secondActivity if you want to send back data

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

if you don't want to return data

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

Now in your FirstActivity class write following code for `onActivityResult()` method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

  String result=data.getStringExtra("result");

}

if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

 //Write your code on no result return 

}
}//onAcrivityResult
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
meditfrom.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Maulik J its already going to be a string.My problem is when i select for 1st edittext it will dispaly what the user selected,and when i select 2nd edit textbox it will dispaly only the 2nd edittextbox value 1st textbox value is empty.

Comment: go with SharedPreferences concept