# Edit Text values get empty

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Edittext values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412784/getting-edittext-values)

I have two screens. In the 1st screen I have two edit boxes. When touching the 1st edit box, it will display a list of values. From that, I can select one value and set it as input for the 1st edit text. Same process will happen for the 2nd edit box.

The problem is when I set input for the 2nd edit box, the 1st edit box goes empty.

My code:

**Ontouch of edittext:**

```
meditfrom.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent  FromIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(),Fromlist.class);
                 startActivityForResult(FromIntent,REQUEST_CODE);   
                 return false;
            }
        });

        meditto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {       
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent  ToIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(),Tolist.class);
                 startActivityForResult(ToIntent,REQUEST_CODE); 
                 return false;
            }
        });
```

**Selection from list view:**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
//                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Intent prev=new Intent(view.getContext(),ServiceExampleActivity.class);
                  prev.putExtra("Fromunit",((TextView) view).getText());
                  setResult(RESULT_OK,prev);
                  finish();
//                startActivity(prev);
              }
            });        
        }
```

**Onactivity result code:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {           
            EditText meditfrom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
            EditText meditto=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) 
            {               

             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
             {                 
                  final String fromunit=data.getStringExtra("Fromunit");
                  System.out.println("string="+fromunit);
                  meditfrom.setText(fromunit);    
            }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you choose this method? You can choose the [AutoComplete TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) And, also have you got any exceptions?

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412784/getting-edittext-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412784/getting-edittext-values)

Comment: [Exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10412784/940096)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using Spinner/Context/AutocompleteTextView menu to give user the list of option to select why you are making it so complex. Also post the code of onActivityResult